How to prove that there exist a unique integer in between a real number and it incremented by 1
There is a question which is based on the completeness axiom (one have to use the field and order axioms too) of real number system and its resulting theorems. It goes like:

Prove that for any real number $x$, there exists a unique integer $n$ such that $x≤n<x+1$.

Now, I tried to prove it by considering the set:
$$S=\{y\in \mathbb{R}:y>n\} \text{ with }x\in S$$
$$\implies \text{inf }S=n$$
With the conditions that:
$$x\in S \text{ and } x-1<n$$
The second condition is implied using the theorem:

Let $h$ be a positive number and $S$ be a set of real numbers with a infimum, then $x-1<\text{inf }S$ for some $x\in S$.

Clearly, those conditions give us:
$$n<x≤n+1\implies n+1<x+1≤n+2$$
Combining the two, we get:
$$x≤n+1<x+1$$
Replacing $n+1$ with another integer $m$, we can say:
$$x≤m<x+1$$
This is all good but how can one show that $m$ or $n+1$ is unique and is this uniqueness even required for the steps taken above and why?

How far apart from  each other must $x$ and $x+1$ be if there were two distinct integers between them?

Also .... you nave $n < x \le n+1$.  Is it possible for there to be an integer $m$ so that $n < m < n+1$?  (Why not?).  And  you have $x \le n+1 < x+1$.  So $x+1\le n+2< x+2$ so you have $n+1 < x+1 \le n+1$.  Is it possible for there to be an integer $k$ so that $n+1 < k < n+2$?

@fleablood Yeah, I thought about this. So, can we directly say that it is unique because integers are seperated by unit distance on number line, so there can be only one in the interval $[x,x+1)$?

@Somos the field, order and completeness axiom as stated by the author

By the very definition of integers (whatever an "integer" is) it must be known that for any integer $k$ that 1) $k+1$ is also an integer and 2) there is no other integer between $k$ and $k+1$.  That must some how either be an axiom or very fundimental early proven property.

But as hint, why don't you do what every single real analysis text in the entire history of the planet does and let $S = {y\in \mathbb Z| y \ge x}$ and consider $\inf S$?

Ooh, dope slap to me.  Your method will never ever work as you can not define $S$ without first having a value for $n$ to use.  So basically you a assuming what you want to prove.   You pretty much have to take a set of integers $S= {m\in \mathbb N|m$ either smaller or larger or equal or smaller or equal or larger than $x$.

You can make a set so that you pick an arbitrary integer $n$ so that $S={y\in R|y> n}$ put you don't know that $x\in S$.  You can assure $x \in S$ by picking $n< x$ (but then you have to prove the integers are not bounded below). Then you have to assure that $x-1 < n$.  You can't do that unless you prove there are integers between $x$ and $x-1$. That is essentially equivalent to what you are attempting to prove.

@fleablood I realised this, that what I am given to prove, I am just assuming. Can you please write an answer if you will. Anyway, I got your point and would try to rectify it.

I don't want to write an answer as I'm sure this is a standard question that has been asked many times and is answered elsewhere and I've been dinged too many times for that.  BUT as an outline: Let $S={n\in \mathbb Z:n \le x}$. $S$ is not empty. (Why?). And bounded above by $x$. So let $w=\sup S$. Prove that $w$ is an integer.(Hint: Let $0< \epsilon < 1$ and consider $n\in S$ so that $w-\epsilon<n\le w$. Can you prove $n=w$?).  Then argue that $w \le x \le w+1$ (Note $w+1$ is an integer and it is strictly larger than $\sup S$). You're done.

There's this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451001/proof-of-the-greatest-integer-theorem-for-every-real-number-x-there-exists-a and  this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4303941/rigorous-definition-of-the-greatest-integer-function
